# Shortcut fusion optimization in javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have heard that lodash and other javascript libraries use a technique called 'shortcut fusion' for optimization but couldn't find a detailed explanation of the technique anywhere.

Can anyone provide a link or explain with an example what 'shortcut fusion' means?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Short_cut_fusion ([what I searched for](https://www.google.com/search?q=shortcut+fusion))

Comment: thanks. I searched for 'javascript shortcut fusion'. Would still love to see an example with javascript functions/data-strucutres being fused.

Comment: The [Lodash docs say this](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash): "The execution of chained methods is lazy, that is, it's deferred until `value()` is implicitly or explicitly called. Lazy evaluation allows several methods to support shortcut fusion. Shortcut fusion is an optimization to merge iteratee calls; this avoids the creation of intermediate arrays and can greatly reduce the number of iteratee executions. Sections of a chain sequence qualify for shortcut fusion if the section is applied to an array and iteratees accept only one argument." But yes, deeper details would be good.

Answer (score 3):

For a very short and unclear explanation - https://wiki.haskell.org/Short_cut_fusion

I still couldn't find a detailed explanation, even for Haskell. The closest to detailed explanation i could find was in a chapter in a book - http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-32037-8_12#page-1

The chapter is available for free as a pdf - http://www.fing.edu.uy/~pardo/papers/tfp2011.pdf

More papers -

- Shortcut fusion for accumulation parameters & zip-like functions - http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~josefs/publications/fusion.pdf
- Short Cut Fusion of Recursive Programs with Computational Effects - https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/neil.ghani/papers/ghani-tfp08.pdf

This looks like a rabbit hole of academic papers. Most useful links on 'shortcut fusion' are for super geeky/mathematical academic papers. Bit much more than i can chew here.

P.S. - Will keep updating this answer with more details as i find them.

Comment: Some say he's still looking for details on shortcut fusion to this day...